# Website not loading CSS after refresh in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, refresh, loading

So there is this site-> http://www.raudsilla.ee

This problem occurs only in Chrome- whenever you press refresh the page loses its CSS. Weird thing is that if you look the code of both- after and before refresh, they look exactly the same. And again, only happens in chrome.

I have tried quite may things, so far no luck...
I wouldn't like to rule out anything at the moment, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you used Firebug/Fiddler to see the HTTP requests? If not, do that to ensure the file is requested and loaded successfully.

Comment: Do you know you're bringing down a 3MB PNG file?  Just askin'.

Comment: Try to remove one by one plugin. I think that you have some javascript that is blockin load of css after refresh.

Answer (score 5):

The browser is outputting javascript errors, if you check the code, you're calling jQuery's document ready before the script is loaded, as it says, "$ is not defined".

After fixing the existing javascript error, it should load correctly.

Comment: I fixed this thing and it's still broken.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing the same behavior on one of our own sites and started looking for a cause. The only conclusion I could come up with for now is that it is caused by the Mime Type of your stylesheet. This conclusion is supported by the behavior on our side.

**Update:**
There are three ways in which Chrome seems to load the CSS file:

- As a fresh request, no cached version available, our server returns `HTTP 200 OK`, with content-type `text/css`. This works fine.
- From the cache, without consulting the server. Chrome has cached content-type `text/css`. This works fine.
- As a request with a cached version available. Our server returns `HTTP 304 Not Modified`, with content-type `text/plain`. This does not work.

Comment: Also: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/zID6uQQfKH8

Answer (score 2):

After some crazy tests, I found the solution by adding "?" to the url css file.

Example: `href="../_css/setup_system.css?" type="text/css"`

Comment: Today I had the same strange problem (css not refreshing) on a very simple web page running on localhost on a friend's Windows PC. The "?" solution fixed it. A good explanation of the solution (forcing a stop to caching) is here: https://csswizardry.com/2019/03/cache-control-for-civilians/.  But I am still puzzled as to why the caching is occuring.  After ~20 yrs of web development, I've never before seen this happen.  Any chance that the firewall / Kaspersky Internet Security is forcing the caching that occurs when not using the query character after the filename?

Answer (score 2):

site.css was not loading in Chrome.  I added the ? in the CSS url and my styles started appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Shift + Refresh solves the problem so it must be a cache problem.
PS . The site takes quite a long time to load, considered optimising?

Comment: Design was quite strict with this one :)

Still tho, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

desable addblock and refresh, if the website loaded correctly check the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Open the console(ctrl + shift + c) and then network panel and check the disable cache button.

[image]